# cachedResponse has no headers

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker, workbox

I am trying to determine how old a cached response is using the date header of the response. I did this with a plugin that uses `cachedResponseWillBeUsed`. However, accessing `cachedResponse.headers` give me nothing. Is this intended? Code attached:

```js
const cachedResponsePlugin = {
  cachedResponseWillBeUsed: ({ cachedResponse }) => {
    let headers = new Headers(cachedResponse.headers);
    console.log(cachedResponse.headers); // Empty
    headers.set("X-Cached-Response", "true");

    return cachedResponse.arrayBuffer().then((buffer) => {
      return new Response(buffer, {
        status: cachedResponse.status,
        statusText: cachedResponse.statusText,
        headers,
      });
    });
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two points in answering your question:

#### Logging Headers in the console

`console.log(cachedResponse.headers)` won't, in general, log anything useful in most browsers. (In Chrome, it just logs `Headers {}`.)

The [`Headers` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/Headers) is [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols), but `console.log()` won't automatically iterate over its values for you. Instead, you need to explicitly iterate as part of your logging. The easiest way to do that, I've found, is to use `...` to iterate, and then wrap the result in `[]` to collect the values into an array.

Putting that together, `console.log([...cachedResponse.headers])` should show you the values you're looking for.

#### Reading the headers

Generally speaking, response headers are preserved when writing to the Cache Storage API.

For cross-origin responses, only a subset of headers will be available when you read that response from a cache. (Workbox automatically reads from the cache for you when it generates the `cachedResponse` parameter.)

There are more details about this, as well as guidance on using the [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers` response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) when serving your cross-origin responses, in this [blog post](https://jeffy.info/2019/07/22/exposing-cors-headers.html).

If you're dealing with a same-origin response, then setting that header shouldn't be necessary, but it's possible you just missed the fact that the header was available due to the logging issue mentioned above.